# Mvvm light messenger initialization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am using mvvm light messenger to make some project with many different Views.
All Views communicate with each other. In few words I have content control that switching Views(SomeInfoCarsView,SomeInfoBicyclesView). Both of these Views(SomeInfoCarsView,SomeInfoBicyclesView) contains "BuyPanelView".
After switching (SomeInfoBicyclesView) sending message to "BuyPanelView".

```
        SendData();
        //Action TimeDelay = new Action(Hold);
        //IAsyncResult result =TimeDelay.BeginInvoke(null,null);
```

Message does not appear in "BuyPanel" because how i thing they have different speed of initialization. But it work's fine if Message send's with some time delay. 
1) Is it normal to use one View inside another View?
2) How to send message without delay in this case?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="DisplayCars" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding DisplayCars}"/>
    <Button Content="DisplayBicycles" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding DisplayBicycles}"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindows.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication95.ViewModel
{
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    readonly static Cars cars = new Cars();
    readonly static Bicycles bicycles = new Bicycles();

    private ViewModelBase currentViewModel ;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return currentViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (currentViewModel == value)
                return;
            currentViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
            public ICommand DisplayCars { get;set; }
            public ICommand DisplayBicycles { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel.cars;
        DisplayCars = new RelayCommand(() => SetCars());
        DisplayBicycles = new RelayCommand(()=>SetBicycles());
    }
    public void SetCars()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel.cars;
    }
    public void SetBicycles()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel.bicycles;
    }
}
}
```

App.xaml:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Cars}">
        <views:SomeInfoCarsView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Bicycles}">
        <views:SomeInfoBicyclesView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

SomeInfoBicycles.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsBicycles}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding .}"></Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <views:BuyPanelView></views:BuyPanelView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

SomeInfoBicycle.cs:

```
 public class SomeInfoBicycles : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the SomeInfoBicycles class.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public ObservableCollection<string> ItemsBicycles { get; set; }
    public SomeInfoBicycles()
    {
        ItemsBicycles = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        ItemsBicycles.Add("First Bicycle");
        ItemsBicycles.Add("Second Bicycle");
        ItemsBicycles.Add("Third Bicycle");
        SendData();
        //Action TimeDelay = new Action(Hold);
        //IAsyncResult result =TimeDelay.BeginInvoke(null,null);
    }
    public void Hold()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        SendData();
    }
    public void SendData()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send<MessageCommunicator>(new MessageCommunicator { Data = ItemsBicycles[1] });
    }

}
```

BuyPanel.cs:

```
 public class BuyPanel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the BuyPanel class.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    private string inputData;
    public string InputData 
    {
        get { return inputData; }
        set { inputData = value; RaisePropertyChanged("InputData"); }
    }
    public BuyPanel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<MessageCommunicator>(this, (emp) => { InputData = emp.Data; });
        Debug.WriteLine(InputData);
    }
}
```

BuyPanel.View:

```
    <StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{Binding InputData}"></Label>
    <Button>Buy</Button>
</StackPanel>
```